# Vb.Net - Having Problems Extracting Wildcard Value

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I've been having problems extracting the value of a Regex in a String. I have a string with several regex expressions and I need to get the value of each expression's match. The thing is though, it's not returning the last match correctly. For example:

**Regex Pattern:** `I play (\S+.*?) and (\S+.*?)`

**String:** I play the guitar and the bass

The program is returning the value of the first expression as "the guitar" but it's returning the value of the second expression as "the" instead of "the bass". Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `I play (\S+.*) and (\S+.*)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you ask for a match with a minimum length using the `.*?`, so there you go.

It works fine for the first group becase `and` is an anchor. For the second group, there's no anchor, thus the minimum match.

Try adding the end of string marker as an anchor: `I play (\S+.*?) and (\S+.*?)$`

Comment: Well but the problem is that I need to use the same pattern for both regex expressions, they can't be different.

Comment: @Leonardo But they are same. The marker belongs to the regex as a whole, not to the second group. You wouldn't say the second group is different from the first group because it has "and" in front of it, whereas the first group has "play" in front of it instead, would you?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know where these regular expressions will appear, the program will decide where to put them, so I won't have a way of knowing on which one to put the $

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `I play (\S+.+) and (\S+.+)`

Comment: That helped a bit, but I'm not quite there yet. The Regex won't match if I only have one character between the "play" and the "end" (I need it to match anything with at last one non-whitespace character)